# How to create a popup with partial left border?

Tags: css

I have to create this modal with same style:

[image]

This is what I have right now:

```css
.notification {
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  width: 460px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 36px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 12px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 999999;
}
    
.notification > .border {
  background-color: #3fb4e4;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 36px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="notification"><div class="border"></div>Hello</div>
```

But I cant find a way to create the blue border on the left.

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple background like below:

```css
.notification {
  border-radius: 36px;
  padding:50px;
  width:100px;
  box-shadow: 
    0 7px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
    0 5px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
    0 12px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);


  /* Relevant code*/
  border:3px solid transparent; /* Control the thickness*/
  background:
    /* Cover only the padding area*/
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
    /* Cover the border area: adjust the 50px to control the size */
    linear-gradient(to right, #3fb4e4 50px,transparent 0) border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">Hello</div>
```

Another syntax where you can control the size outside the gradient:

```css
.notification {
  border-radius: 36px;
  padding:50px;
  width:100px;
  box-shadow: 
    0 7px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
    0 5px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
    0 12px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);


  /* Relevant code*/
  border:3px solid transparent; /* Control the thickness*/
  background:
    /* Cover only the padding area*/
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
    /* Cover the border area */
    linear-gradient(#3fb4e4,#3fb4e4) left border-box no-repeat;
  background-size:50px 100%;
  transition:0.6s;
}

.notification:hover {
  background-size: 100px 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Any clue on how to add the X button correct? Is it possible to add the style into the same class or better to have a nested DIV just for the X button? Thanks

Comment: @VAAA you need to have the X as an extra DIV because you will trigger some event on it to close the popup. It will not simply be a visual styling

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a border on the container itself:

```
.notification {
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  width: 460px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 36px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 12px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 999999;
  border-left: 3px solid #3fb4e4;
}
```